# getline() doesn't get input from the user after using cin

Tags: c++

When I use `cin` to get a string from the user, then use `getline()` after it, the compiler skips over `getline()` and doesn't get input from the user.

```
cout << "What is your name: ";
string name;
cin >> name;
cout << "What is your favorite book: ";
string book;
getline(cin, book);
```

Output:

> What is your name: **Example Input**
> What is your favorite book:
> *Program exists*

I tried using `cin.ignore()` but I don't know what to put exactly in the parameters.

Comment: Change `cin >> name;` to `getline(cin, name);`

Comment: string book;
  string name;
  std::cout << "What is your name: ";

std::cin >> name;
std::cout << "What is your favorite book: ";

std::cin.ignore();
std::getline(std::cin, name);